# Peer to peer VS Multicasting VS SMB : Which is best method?

Tags: windows, p2p, multicast, smb

I am searching for the best practices to implement in my project.

My project is like of transferring bulk data from single server into multiple clients. In brief, I am having a server machine which have a file of minimum of 100MB to maximum of 4 GB file. Once I notify to all clients about that "I am having file. You can download". Then the client should start downloading that files. Here all clients must stay in same network. I might consider load balancing in server too.

I planned to use peer to peer connection like torrent but it needs more study (I think so).

But I felt implementing multicast is easy. But my fear is it is not reliable.

I have also another suggestion, how about copying file from network path like SMB.

Please give me some suggestionns which is the best method to follow.

Kindly revert back for any clarifications.

Thanks and Regards,

Thiyagz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, multi-casting is better way and also an easiest way.
Now we have many reliable multicast protocols.
You can find sources like OpenPGM, which is a reliable multicast supported one.
Or just try **[multicast socket programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739172(v=vs.85).aspx) by using Windows API**.